# Very basic Lie Algebras question on the complex conjugate of the adjoint map

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

$V$ vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, $L$ Lie subalgebra (subspace and closed under Lie bracket) of $gl(V)$, linear maps $V \to V$. Suppose $d \in L$ diagonalisable, show that $\overline{ad(d)} = ad(\bar{d})$ (bar represents complex conjugate).

I have that $d$ is diagonalisable so there exists a basis $B$ of $V$ such that $[d]_B$ is diagonal, where $[d]_B$ is the matrix of $d$ with respect to $B$.

I think I am missing something obvious, we need to show that $\forall x \in L, \overline{ad(d)}(x) = \overline{[d, x]} = \overline{dx - xd}$ is equal to $\bar{d}x - x\bar{d} = [\bar{d}, x] = ad(\bar{d})$ but I just can't think of how to show $\overline{dx - xd} = \bar{d}x - x\bar{d}$.

I thought we could work with matrices but I run into the same problem, I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Any hints or help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a counterexample. Let $L=\mathfrak{gl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $d=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &  0 \cr 0 & i \end{pmatrix}$, $x=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &  i \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Then we have
$$
\overline{[d,x]}=\overline{dx-xd}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &  1-i \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
$$
but
$$
[\overline{d},x]=\overline{d}x-x\overline{d}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &  i-1 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Do you have a link for the question ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the sheet has another question missing a criteria so this might be a similar issue. The sheet is located at http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/undergrad/ughandbook/lecturers/ma453/lie_algebras_3.pdf but I don't think you can access it unless you are a student or staff at Warwick. A screenshot of the sheet (question 1) is here: http://imgur.com/fDSr0Sx , question 2b is missing the non-degenerate criteria so perhaps question 1 is missing a criteria (could you think of any that apply?). I might have miscalculated $\overline{ad(d)}$ but that is all I can think of.

Comment: I will accept your answer once I determine if the question is incorrect or not by the way, just want it to remain unanswered for now in case someone else has an insight too. Thanks.

Comment: You can come up with more examples like this, which differ not only by a sign, but are completely different, e.g. with $x=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &  1+i \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and some diagonal $d$.

Comment: Oh I believe you don't get me wrong, I was just unsure if I had interpreted the question's idea of the commutator wrong. I'll email my lecturer, thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

The equality you want to prove is $\overline{ad(d)} = ad(\overline{d})$ which is **not** equivalent to $\overline{dx - xd} = \bar{d}x - x\bar{d}$.

If $d = \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n)$, then $ad(d) = \text{diag}(\lambda_i - \lambda_j)$, where $1 \leq i,j \leq n$. More precisely, $ad(d)$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_i - \lambda_j$ corresponding to eigenvectors $E_{ij}$. Therefore $$\overline{ad(d)} = \overline{\text{diag}(\lambda_i - \lambda_j)}  = \text{diag}(\overline{\lambda_i - \lambda_j}) = \text{diag}(\overline{\lambda_i} - \overline{\lambda_j}) = ad(\overline{d}).$$